# CakePHP 3.6.x CSRF Token Mismatch

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x, cakephp-3.6

I am attempting to post an AJAX request to a controller method...

I have done the following per the instructions on https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/csrf.html#csrf-protection-and-ajax-requests

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
    $this->Security->config('unlockedActions', ['galleryReorder']);

    if (in_array($this->request->action, ['galleryReorder'])) {
        $this->eventManager()->off($this->Csrf);
    }

    return parent::beforeFilter($event); 
}
```

However, the beforeFilter method does not seem to be firing, and I continue to get a CSRF Token Mismatch...

Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Are you using the CSRF middleware? If so, the solution for skipping CSRF protection on a request is quite different.

Comment: I believe I am, how do i go about skipping the middleware csrf protection?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disabling CSRF on a specific action CakePHP 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31018156/disabling-csrf-on-a-specific-action-cakephp-3)

Comment: Check the second answer.

Comment: @GregSchmidt That's not an overly good example though, as accessing superglobals directly should be avoided whenever possible - unless of course you _want_ to mess up the test environment ;) Not that I want to shill for myself, but check for example **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47714940/cakephp-3-5-6-disable-csrf-middleware-for-controller** for an idea on how to use routes and custom middlewares to apply CSRF protection partially/conditionally.

Comment: Good point, I didn't look closely enough at the implementation details there, just the broad strokes.